# How to create a VF page that searches on knowledge articles that match description

Tags: visualforce, knowledge, articles

I have a field in my form called Description. Depending on what the user enters, I want to open a VF page that searches knowledge articles with this information and returns the results.

Answer (score 1):

The developers guide contains a section on using visualforce to create a knowledge search
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/knowledge_dev/salesforce_knowledge_dev_guide.pdf